# How to get the number of days in a month?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, date-arithmetic

I am trying to get the following in Postgres:

```
select day_in_month(2);
```

Expected output:

```
28
```

Is there any built-in way in Postgres to do that?

Comment: With regards to your example, have you heard of leap years (or is there an implicit assumption that this is for the *current* year)?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
SELECT  
    DATE_PART('days', 
        DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) 
        + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL 
        - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL
    )
```

Substitute `NOW()` with any other date.

Comment: I would replace the second `DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW())` with `'1 day'::interval`

Comment: @sayap's correction is crucial; the solution can otherwise lead to bad results (try, e.g., `'2006-04-30'::date`) in place of `NOW()`

Comment: AWS redshift error: internal values with month or year parts are not supported

Comment: @giò: redshift is not postgresql

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can replace `NOW()` with a time stamp in some format. How can I modify this code to get as input simply year and month, as two numbers, or a string `2020-12` for example?

Comment: @icemtel: `'2020-12-01'::DATE`

Comment: `DATE_PART('days', DATE_ADD('days', -1, DATE_ADD('month', 1, DATE_TRUNC('month', <date>)))) ` works

Comment: strange there isn't simpler way to do it - but awsm - thx so much!

Answer (score 11):

Using the smart "trick" to extract the *day* part from the last date of the month, as [demonstrated by Quassnoi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927213/939860). But it can be a bit simpler / faster:

```
SELECT extract(days FROM date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month - 1 day');
```

#### Rationale

`extract` is standard SQL, so maybe preferable, but it resolves to the same function internally as `date_part()`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT)

> The `date_part` function is modeled on the traditional Ingres equivalent to the SQL-standard function `extract`:

But we only need to add **a *single* `interval`**. Postgres allows multiple time units at once. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT)

> `interval` values can be written using the following verbose syntax:
>
> `[@]` *`quantity unit`*`[`*`quantity unit`*`...] [`*`direction`*`]`
>
> where *`quantity`* is a number (possibly signed); *`unit`* is `microsecond`,
> `millisecond`, `second`, `minute`, `hour`, `day`, `week`, `month`, `year`, `decade`,
> `century`, `millennium`, or abbreviations or plurals of these units;

[ISO 8601 or standard SQL format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT-EXAMPLES) are also accepted. Either way, [the manual again](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT):

> Internally `interval` values are stored as months, days, and seconds.
> This is done because the number of days in a month varies, and a day
> can have 23 or 25 hours if a daylight savings time adjustment is
> involved. The months and days fields are integers while the seconds
> field can store fractions.

(Output / display depends on the [setting of `IntervalStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#INTERVAL-STYLE-OUTPUT-TABLE).)

The above example uses **default Postgres format**: `interval '1 month - 1 day'`. These are also valid (while less readable):

```
interval '1 mon - 1 d' -- unambiguous abbreviations of time units are allowed
```

**IS0 8601 format**:

```
interval '0-1 -1 0:0'
```

**Standard SQL format**:

```
interval 'P1M-1D';
```

All the same.

Answer (score 2):

Note that expected output for day_in_month(2) can be 29 because of leap years. You might want to pass a date instead of an int.

Also, beware of daylight saving : remove the timezone or else some monthes calculations could be wrong (next example in CET / CEST) :

```
SELECT  DATE_TRUNC('month', '2016-03-12'::timestamptz) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL
      - DATE_TRUNC('month', '2016-03-12'::timestamptz) ;
------------------
 30 days 23:00:00

SELECT  DATE_TRUNC('month', '2016-03-12'::timestamp) + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL
      - DATE_TRUNC('month', '2016-03-12'::timestamp) ;
----------
 31 days
```

Comment: The 23 hours in example, Does that mean there is daylight saving time ?

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT
    (
        timestamp '2024-01-01' + INTERVAL '1 month'
    ) - timestamp '2024-01-01' AS days
-- 31 days
```

The subtracting two timestamps will always produce an interval in terms of days. We won't just get an answer in terms of months or years, because the length of those time periods is variable.

Answer (score 0):

This works as well.

```
WITH date_ AS (SELECT your_date AS d)
SELECT d + INTERVAL '1 month' - d FROM date_;
```

Or just:

```
SELECT your_date + INTERVAL '1 month' - your_date;
```

These two return *interval*, not *integer*.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT cnt_dayofmonth(2016, 2);  -- 29


create or replace function cnt_dayofmonth(_year int, _month int)
returns int2 as
$BODY$
-- ZU 2017.09.15, returns the count of days in mounth, inputs are year and month
declare 
    datetime_start date := ('01.01.'||_year::char(4))::date;
    datetime_month date := ('01.'||_month||'.'||_year)::date;
        cnt int2;
begin 
  select extract(day from (select (datetime_month + INTERVAL '1 month -1 day'))) into cnt;

  return cnt;
end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Answer (score -3):

You can write a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_total_days_in_month(timestamp)
RETURNS decimal
IMMUTABLE
AS $$
  select cast(datediff(day, date_trunc('mon', $1), last_day($1) + 1) as decimal)
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: There is no function `datediff()` in Postgres (unless you create a custom function). Nor `last_day()`.