# How to get number of days in month based on date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to use extract from date in format `YYYY-MM-DD` how many days were in this month?

example:

for `2016-02-05` it will give `29`   (Feb 2016 has 29 days)

for `2016-03-12` it will give `31`

for `2015-02-05` it will give `28`   (Feb 2015 had 28 days)

I'm using PostgreSQL

**EDIT:**

[LAST_DAY function in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229038/last-day-function-in-postgres) is not what i'm looking for. it returns DATE while I expect an Integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LAST\_DAY function in postgres](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229038/last-day-function-in-postgres)

Comment: @sagi this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @java Possible duplicate of [How to get the number of days in a month in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927113/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-in-a-month-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to subtract the beginning of the following month from the beginning of the current month:

```
db=> SELECT DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', '2016-02-05'::DATE + INTERVAL '1 MONTH') - 
            DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', '2016-02-05'::DATE);
 ?column? 
----------
 29 days
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just needed this today and seems that I came up with pretty much the same as Mureinik, just that I needed it numeric. (PostgreSQL couldn't convert from interval to number directly)

**previous month**:

```
select CAST(to_char(date_trunc('month', current_date) - (date_trunc('month', current_date) - interval '1 month'),'dd') as integer)
```

**current month**:

```
select CAST(to_char(date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month' - date_trunc('month', current_date), 'dd') as integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try next:

```
SELECT  
  DATE_PART('days', 
    DATE_TRUNC('month', TO_DATE('2016-02-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) 
    + '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL 
    - DATE_TRUNC('month', TO_DATE('2016-02-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
  );
```

Note: there date is used twice. And used convert function `TO_DATE`