# Storing hours, minutes and seconds effectively

Tags: postgresql, time, types

Using a PostgreSQL database, what is the best way to store time, in hours, minutes and seconds. E.g. "40:21" as in *40 minutes and 21 seconds*.

Example data:

```
   20:21
 1:20:02
12:20:02
   40:21
```

Comment: [Date/Time Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to store time above 24:00:00 in postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465991/best-way-to-store-time-above-240000-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 5):

[**`time`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) would be the obvious candidate to store time as you describe it.  It enforces the range of daily time (`00:00:00` to `24:00:00`) and occupies **8 bytes**.

**`interval`** allows arbitrary intervals, even negative ones, or even a mix of positive and negative ones like `'1 month - 3 seconds'` - doesn't fit your description well - and occupies **16 bytes**. See:

- [How to get the number of days in a month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927113/how-to-get-the-number-of-days-in-a-month/50766911#50766911)

To optimize storage size, make it an **`integer`** (**4 bytes**) signifying seconds. To convert `time` back and forth:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM time '18:55:28');  -- 68128 (int)    
SELECT time '00:00:01' * 68128;              -- '18:55:28' (time)
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to store a length of time, or interval. PostgreSQL has a special interval type to store a length of time, e.g.

```
SELECT interval'2 hours 3 minutes 20 seconds';
```

This can be added to a timestamp in order to form a new timestamp, or multiplied (so that (2 * interval'2 hours') = interval'4 hours'. The interval type seems to tailor-made for your use case.